# What is the problem when KeyListener is added yet keyEvent is not working when pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

My Listener is added to the JFrame/JPanel. The problem is that when I pressed a button, nothing is happening. What might be the problem here?

The following are the codes used:

```
public class GAMEGAMEHA extends JPanel{

    public static JFrame PacmanMainFrame = new JFrame();
    TheJGame newGame;

    GAMEGAMEHA() {
        setSize(new Dimension(1200, 700));
        JLabel BG = new JLabel();
        JButton start = new JButton();
        JButton howTo = new JButton();
        JButton credit = new JButton();
        JButton exit = new JButton();

        setLayout(null);

        start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/data/SB.png")));

        start.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        start.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            newGame = new TheJGame();
            GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            System.out.println("Removed Components");
            GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.add(newGame);
            System.out.println("Added Game");
            GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.addKeyListener(newGame);
            System.out.println("Added KeyListeners");
            GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Set Visiblity to True");
        });

        start.setBorderPainted(false);
        add(start);
        start.setBounds(440, 140, 300, 70);

        howTo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/data/HowToButton.jpg")));
        howTo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e
            ) {
                HowTo HowToScreen = new HowTo();
                GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.add(HowToScreen);
                GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        howTo.setBorderPainted(false);
        add(howTo);

        howTo.setBounds(440, 220, 300, 70);

        credit.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/data/CreditsButton.jpg")));
        credit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e
            ) {
                Credit CreditScreen = new Credit();
                GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
                GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.add(CreditScreen);
                GAMEGAMEHA.PacmanMainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        credit.setBorderPainted(false);
        add(credit);

        credit.setBounds(440, 300, 300, 70);

        exit.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/data/ExitButton.jpg")));
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e
            ) {
                System.exit(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        }
        );
        exit.setBorderPainted(
                false);
        add(exit);

        exit.setBounds(
                440, 380, 300, 70);

        BG.setIcon(
                new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/data/MainMenu.jpg")));
        BG.setText(
                "BackgroundImage");
        add(BG);

        BG.setBounds(
                0, 0, 1200, 700);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GAMEGAMEHA GameMENU = new GAMEGAMEHA();
        PacmanMainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(1200, 700));
        PacmanMainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        PacmanMainFrame.setTitle("THE JUNGLE GAME: A Object-Oriented Programming Project");
        PacmanMainFrame.setResizable(false);
        PacmanMainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        PacmanMainFrame.add(GameMENU);
        PacmanMainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This is game started:
The problem is here. The Main menu is good but when going here, it doesn't accept nor read any key.

```
public class TheJGame extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    BackgroundGame BG = new BackgroundGame();
    MainCharacter bens = new MainCharacter();
    static int MainCx = 22;
    static int MainCy = 20;
    static int BGx = 0;
    static int BGy = 545;

    TheJGame() {
        bens.initializeMChar();
        BG.initializeGGround();
        setBounds(0, 0, 1200, 700);
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 1200, 700);
        g.drawImage(BG.GGround, BGx, BGy, this);
        g.drawImage(BG.GGround, BGx + 1200, BGy, this);
        g.drawImage(bens.MCharacter, MainCx, MainCy, this);
        updateBG();
        updateFall();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            MainCy+=5;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void updateFall() {

        if (MainCy <= 445) {
            MainCy += 1;
            repaint();
        }

    }

    private void updateBG() {
        BGx -= 1;

        if (BGx == -1200) {
            BGx = 0;
        }

        repaint();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Main Problem

The "major" problem is, `KeyListener` is a poor choice for monitoring keyboard input in Swing, it suffers from a focus issue, where the component it is registered to must be focusable AND have keyboard focus and since you're adding buttons to the UI, they will steal focus from the component.

A better, overall solution, is to use the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which gives you the control to determine at what level of focus the bindings should be triggered

## Additional problems...

`null` layouts are notoriously difficult to manage and maintain.  There are a lot of factors which go into determining how best a component should appear on the screen.  You should avoid `null` layouts where possible and make use of one or more layout managers, they will save a lot of your hair

You've overriding `paint`, but you've failed to honour the paint chain (by not calling `super.paint`).  Painting is a complex process, made up of a number of steps.

As a general rule, you should override `paintComponent` (and call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting).

Have a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more details about painting in Swing

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the key listener to the JPnael simply implementing the interface is not enough you have to add it to the panel.

```
addKeyListner(this);
```

Add this line of code to your constructor.

Comment: You say that you added the listener but I can't see it in your code.

Comment: If you have it added then post the code snippet so that we can inspect it for mistakes.

Comment: And y the way keyListeners work only when your frame is in focus so make sure you have it.